# Deep nested validation in loopback models

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback, loopback4

The loopback docs indicate how to [validate models in the REST layer](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Validation-REST-layer.html). But, is there a way you can validate deep/nested models inside your model?

If a User has both a name and a Contact, I want both to be validated, including all properties defined in Contact.

[This comment](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/1698#issuecomment-143163032) from 2015 mentions deep validation is not supported. Is this still the case?

In this more recent [answer](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5611#issuecomment-636300057) it is suggested to set `type: Contact` directly, but I'm getting this error:

```
Property User.contact does not have "type" in its definition
```

```
import {Entity, model, property} from '@loopback/repository';

// User
@model()
export class User extends Entity {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @property({
    type: Contact, 
    required: true,
  })
  contact: Contact;
}

// Contact
@model()
export class Contact extends Model {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    default: 'phone',
  })
  type: string;
}
```